# how to retrieve an active storage attachment url as json in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, json, ruby, api

I'm trying to retrieve the URL of an active storage attachment as JSON response but i didn't quite get the correct respond here is my code:

**#projet.rb**

```
class Projet < ApplicationRecord
 has_many :appartements, dependent: :destroy
 has_one_attached :image_de_couverture
 has_one_attached :situation
 has_many_attached :images
end
```

**#projet_serializer.rb**

```
class ProjetSerializer < ActiveModel::Serializer
  include Rails.application.routes.url_helpers
  attributes :id, :nom, :gouvernorat, :localite, :surface, :description, :en_cours, :fini, 
  :situation, :images, :image_de_couverture

  def images
    object.images.map do |image|
      rails_blob_path(image, only_path: true) if object.images.attached?
    end
  end

  def image_de_couverture
    polymorphic_url(object.image_de_couverture, only_path: true) if 
    object.image_de_couverture.attached?
  end

  def situation
    polymorphic_url(object.situation, only_path: true) if object.situation.attached?
  end
end
```

**#projets_controller.rb**

```
class ProjetsController < ApplicationController
  # show all projects
  def index
    @projets = Projet.all
    render json: @projets
  end

  def set_projet
    @projet = Projet.find(params[:id])
  end

  def projet_params
    params.require(:projet).permit(:nom, :gouvernorat, :localite, :surface, :description, :situation, images: [])
  end
end
```

and here is the response i get with this code

```
[
  {
  id: 1,
  nom: "Test",
  gouvernorat: "Test",
  localite: "Test",
  surface: 30303,
  description: "Test",
  en_cours: true,
  fini: true,
  situation: "/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--50589feef3ab662f5fb9877dbf4f0a21c79e2412/lame_rideau1.jpg",
  images: [
  "/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--0550f31bd4e562c76dfd1aff9f0beac6483e1651/1.jpg",
  "/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBFQT09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--11ec06652e38fc43b54ef93187905f4591115d3c/2.jpg",
  ],
  image_de_couverture: null
  },
]
```

instead of

```
"/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--0550f31bd4e562c76dfd1aff9f0beac6483e1651/1.jpg"
```

i want to the link to the attachment.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Unless you have an `as_json` presenter you'll just get the default dump which can be *ugly*.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try changing the `rails_blob_path` helper by `rails_blob_url` in your `ProjetSerializer#images`. You also need to set the host config in your application file. [source](https://edgeguides.rubyonrails.org/active_storage_overview.html#linking-to-files)

```
# config/application.rb

class Application < Rails::Application
  ...
  routes.default_url_options = { host: 'localhost:3000' }
end
```

Answer (score 0):

```ruby
def images
    object.images.map do |image|
      Rails.application.routes.url_helpers.rails_blob_url(image, only_path: true) if object.images.attached?
    end
  end
```

Comment: it gives the same result as my code,

`"/rails/active_storage/blobs/redirect/eyJfcmFpbHMiOnsibWVzc2FnZSI6IkJBaHBEdz09IiwiZXhwIjpudWxsLCJwdXIiOiJibG9iX2lkIn19--0550f31bd4e562c76dfd1aff9f0beac6483e1651/1.jpg"`

Comment: but actually that is the generated link from the active storeage to the image if you click that or send request by postman. what sort of link do you want actually?

Comment: i want a link when i click it it opens the image, this one doesn't do the job @dedypuji